# Trying to resize ▲▼ symbols inside list in a table th, but font-size is ineffective

Tags: html, css, size, special-characters

I want to have a ▲▼ symbol to denote that a specific table column is sortable (e.g. name▲▼ but with the arrows on top of each other).  To get that onto one line I have used a list:

```
<table class="test">
  <tr><th>test <ul><li>&#9650;</li><li>&#9660</li></ul></th></tr>
</table>
```

The arrows are too big and spaced badly.  So, to style the result I used:

```
   th ul{
        display:inline-block;
   }

.test th ul{
    font-size:5px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.test th li{
    font-size:5px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This was meant to make the combined character smaller, but font-size seems to have no effect at all on the size of the symbols.  How should this be done?

Edit: It now seems that this works perfectly in opera and that this is some firefox (my version is the 32 bit linux 20.0 one) specific issue.  In fact it just affects arrow sizes:

```
  <p>&#9650;</p>

body{
    font-size:5px;
}
```

This still results in large arrows.  Can anyone else confirm that it's a firefox only issue?

This is just weird, I'll probably just go with using an image.

Comment: They seem pretty small: http://jsfiddle.net/8YH8y/

Comment: use em instead of pixels. Works for me.

Comment: Do you want to some control over the positioning of the symbols?

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue.  Works in Chrome, FF, and IE9.  (Though there's still dots; you might consider adding `list-style: none outside;` to the rules for the `ul`.)

Comment: Also, IMO 5px makes them a bit too small to be distinguishable; you could make them a couple of pixels bigger and set the `line-height` to 1 to compensate. (http://jsfiddle.net/8YH8y/4/)

Comment: The default fonts used by Linux differ from that used by Windows PC and Macs.  You are getting different visual results because of the combination of browser and OS that you are using.  I am using a Windows PC and everything looks fine, but that does not solve the styling issue for FF on Linux, which is a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. Use a icon font instead of html symbols. https://github.com/aristath/elusive-iconfont

You can also visit a demo page at: http://shoestrap.org/downloads/elusive-icons-webfont/

Alternatively, try http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Both font sets have up/down carets, but not in one symbol.

Comment: Dunno if you've ever actually used a web font before...but there tends to be a bit of a delay between when the text shows up and when the font is applied.  If standard characters in the existing font would work, they'd probably be better.  (Add to that...loading a font for one or two characters seems a bit overkill to me.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<table class="test">
  <tr><th>test <span class="icon-sortable">&#9650;<br>&#9660;</span></th></tr>
</table>
```

with the following CSS:

```
th {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    font-size: 1.00em;
}
.icon-sortable {
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.50em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I would use an inline-block to position the two arrows, a bit easier to style and simpler mark-up (fewer tags).

You can set a font-size for the icon either using relative or absolute units depending on your site's styling.

Use `vertical-align` to position the icon vertically, I used middle, but top, bottom, baseline and other options are available, again depends on your preference.

If you need to move the two symbols close together, you need to wrap them in another tag and adjust the positioning.

I constructed two examples, one basic and the other fancy with more tags to control arrow positioning.

You can also adjust the padding, width, margin of the inline-block for a lot more control.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/XPQPh/

Comment: Unfortunately, this also still leads to large sized arrows in firefox.  I think this is some firefox issue, rather than a css one, since it works fine in opera.

Comment: I am actually working in Firefox... I can control the size of the arrows quite easily.  Are we working on the same code?  If you are using `ul li`, and you don't have a reset CSS style sheet, you may be seeing different effects due to each browser's default style sheet.

Comment: It still happens even when the code consists of <p>&#9650;</p> and nothing else.

Comment: First things first, is my fiddle looking okay?

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine under opera, but arrows are too big in firefox.

Comment: You are using Firefox in Linux, I wonder what the default font-size is in FF under Linux? Are you using a reset style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a minimum font size setting in Firefox, preventing the effect of setting font size to 5 pixels. In general, if you need a font size that small, you really need a different approach.

The size of the characters ▲▼ greatly varies by font, and so does their spacing, so you should have a `font-family` setting for them that suits your needs, possibly a rather large list of fonts, just to be sure (after all, no font is present in all computers).